# How to make a asp.net drop down list responsive

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering how would I make a asp.net drop down list responsive. And by that I mean when I am on my smart phone it will format its width to fit the screen, and when i am on a tablet it would do the same and so on.

Any examples would be great.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you haven't shown us what you've tried so far.  It's expected that you do a little bit of research and trial-and-error before posting a question to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Step 1: Add one or more CSS classes

You'll need to start by adding a CSS class to the dropdown list control (hereafter referred to as '**the control**'). This can be done by adding one or more classes to the CssClass attribute in the control. Additionally you should take a look at conditional CSS statements.

---

### Step 2: Add the usual responsive design styles to the class

A basic responsive design style is something like this

```
.responsiveWidth{width:100%;max-width:950px;min-width:650px;}
```

---

### Things to remember...

Just remember that when using max- and min-width, it is expected that if you use a percent for `width` , then you should use an explicit width for `max-width` and `min-width`. This goes both ways, so you could do:

```
.reponsiveWidth{width:900px;max-width:100%;}
```

...which would keep the control at 900px width unless the screen width drops below 900px.

---

### Bonus Info:

Here are some links that I have in my "Responsive Design" folder in my bookmarks...

**Tips**

- [7 Responsive Design Tips to Enhance Your Workflow](http://mashable.com/2013/04/12/responsive-design-tips/)
- [How to use conditional CSS statements](https://gist.github.com/dryan/453321)
- [5 Useful CSS Tricks for Responsive Design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design)

**References**

- [W3C CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/)
- [Advanced Conditional Statements](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a css class and set the width to a relative size. (100% for example)