# How to alligned/set Layout of Master Page ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, master-pages

Need some help on how to set the layout like normally websites do.

For example : http://www.rachaelray.com/food.php

This website contents appears to be right in the center of the in big, white box and there's light blue colour as the background.

My website would be much simpler.

I don't really have the idea on how to have such (website above) layout for my master page.

Below is what I have done so far :-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

        <style type="text/css">
         #main
          {

           }      
         .left
         {
            margin:0 auto;
            float:left;
            width:20%;
          }
         .right
         {
            margin:0 auto;
            float:right;
            width:20%;
          }
        .content
         {

            width:100%;

          }
        .footer
        {
         padding:5px;
         background:black;
         color:white;
        }
            .wrapper 
            {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 700px;
            }
            .auto-style1 {
                width: 466px;
                image-orientation:auto;
            }
            .auto-style2 {
                width: 466px;
                height: 23px;
            }
            .auto-style3 {
                width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
            }
        </style>

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="left" class="left" > </div>
    <div id="cont" class="wrapper">
        <table class="content">
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:Image ID="Logo_MaduDTrading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/BeforeLogin/Logo_MaduDTrading.jpg" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">

               </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"> 

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">

                &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">

                &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
     <div id="right" class="right"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to center align a website I used a div tag for the main page content and set a width, auto margin left and right. You can also set the body background color to be different from the div tag to create the effect in the example site you provided. For example.

Html in master page:

```
<div class="page">
    Page content here
</div>
```

Css in head or separate .css file:

```
.page {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

You can add a margin top and bottom to add the box in the center of the screen affect. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work. For example, there's a image(logo) in the codes above right ?  When I added your codes, the image is still on the left. How to align that to the center like in the white box of the website that I have provided ?

Comment: Have you included the logo between the <div class='page'> and </div> tags? you can also centre the logo by using the .css style "text-align:centre"

Answer (score 0):

You should be using responsive web design techniques when creating master pages and/or ContentPlaceHolder controls within master pages. This will address the page-centering issue and the width of your objects. It is also how your example site creates their layout.

## How to center your content

As Jonathan Bick mentioned, the most common method for centering your content is by setting the left and right margin to auto on any given div. This can be done with the following:

```
.someClass{margin:0 auto;}
```

---

**Common mistakes when centering your content**

Any of the following can stop your content from centering properly:

- Forgetting to set the width.

  - The width of any centered element must be explicitly set. This can be done with either a percentage of the window, by pixels, or any other *[CSS Unit of measurement](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)*.
- Placing the div within a container that is set to float left or right.

  - Doing this will cause the contained div to disregard its width property. Test it *[here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xp4um/)*

*Note: These are just off the top of my head so I'll come back and add more as I think of them.*

---

## Notes on Responsive Web Design

Responsive web design is used to create a site that auto-adjusts its elements for the best possible layout for the current screen size. The great thing is this can be done purely with CSS and HTML. You can find all you need to get started at the link below...

- **[StackOverflow - How to make an ASP.NET drop down list responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821033/how-to-make-a-asp-net-drop-down-list-responsive/17821359#17821359)**

This should definitely get you pointed in the right direction. That link also has references to some excellent tutorials I have in my "Responsive Design" folder in my bookmarks.

---

## Using Google Chrome's "Inspect element"

Google Chrome (as well as most other browsers) has a tool called *Inspect element*. When you right click on an element in a web-site, at the bottom of the context menu you will see the *Inspect element* option. Clicking on this will pull up a tool that analyses the properties of any rendered element, and displays them with color-coding, images, labeling, etc. The tool is excellent and may help you identify why your image is not centering...

[image: Inspect element example 1]

Here you can see what happens when I inspect the logo of Stack Overflow.

**Furthermore...**

You can use the styles window (at the bottom right of the *Elements* panel) to quickly test out new styles.

[image: Inspect element example 2]

Notice that I changed the border of the logo in the styles section to `solid 20px red` and the new style is reflected in the browser window. This, of course, is only temporary so you need not worry about accidentally breaking your code.